# How to install imagick with heic for alternative php verison?

Tags: php, imagemagick, ubuntu-18.04, imagick

Got server with control panel. Cli working on php 7.2 with alraedy installed imagick with heic support. But my php-fpm with 7.4 version working on another dir, like /opt/php74/bin and got lower imagick lib version.
How to upgrade this version too?

Answer (score 0):

I sorted this out in my installation. Make sure you have "apt install php7.4-dev" rather than for the 7.2. https://eplt.medium.com/5-minutes-to-install-imagemagick-with-heic-support-on-ubuntu-18-04-digitalocean-fe2d09dcef1